# How to stop an LG phone from asking for confirmation when I turn mobile data on/off?

Tags: mobile-data, lg, user-interface

How do I stop an LG phone from asking for confirmation when I turn mobile data on/off?

When I turn it on, it says "data charges may apply" and requires me to tap again for confirmation. When I turn it off, it asks "turn off mobile data?" and requires me to tap again.

Samsung phones don't ask, so tapping on the mobile data icon is more convenient and reliable.

Comment: To my experience LG phones ask a lot of unnecessary questions (e.g. if Air-Plane mode is active after start-up). Now then do no longer produce Android phones...

Comment: @Robert Can this be changed somehow? Surely that's somewhere in configuration/system files or something, but where?

Comment: @root these kind of [annoying] things are, per my observation, not made configurable by phone manufacturers. The best you can do is search thoroughly the Settings app for something that appears related to your problem. Next you can do is, setup adb and list out all the keys and values the Settings app uses internally. Find a key-value that appears related to your problem, take a note of it as a backup, try changing the value, and see if it helps. That's all you can really do at this point. I don't have an LG device so I cannot offer something more hands-on.

Comment: @Firelord I found keys that sound similar, like `data_network_user_paypopup_response` and `show_warning_popup`, but changing them (without a reboot) didn't help...